# Setup compiled executables automatically as Project32.exe and Project64.exe

Tags: delphi

Short question.
How can I setup a Delphi project, to automatically output the compiled executables in the same folder and as `Project32.exe` when selected target platform is `Win32` and `Project64.exe` when selected target platform is `Win64`.

`Project` name is just an example.

For the same folder, I succeed to setup the parameters, as bellow.

[image]

From the options I see, I think is not possible, but who knows... maybe there is an way.

Comment: Don't do this. Change the names when you deploy.

Comment: On a side note, just in case you are interested in a trademark, "Project64" is already taken.

Comment: The aim of this solution is to directly prepare the necessary files for InnoSetup. After setup installation, the name of app inside of Program Files will be `Project.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *Project Options* and select *Build Events*. Then select *All configurations - 32-bit Windows platform*. In the *Post-build events* enter the following sequence under *Commands*:

```
ren $(OUTPUTPATH) $(OUTPUTNAME)32.$(OUTPUTEXT)
```

Now select *All configurations - 64-bit Windows platform* and enter the following sequence accordingly:

```
ren $(OUTPUTPATH) $(OUTPUTNAME)64.$(OUTPUTEXT)
```

Note that you will lose the integrated debugging functionality as the debugger cannot find the exe file anymore.

Comment: I would say that both answers from @Uwe and @Remy (marked a possible solution) helps me to define the final solution. The final command I used is: `copy $(OUTPUTPATH) $(OUTPUTDIR)\$(OUTPUTNAME)32.$(OUTPUTEXT)`